# How to get values from the second column of a 2d array based on the fiest column value?

Tags: java

I have a Set of data. For example:

car accord
car civic
suv landcruzer
suv landrover
muv innova

I want store it in a scanner or hash map and retrieve the values based on the input.

If "car" is the input I want to pass URL+/accord and URL+/civic as its output

If "muv" is the input, I want to pass URL+/innova as its output

```
String URL = "www.abc.com";
String Vehicletype = "";
@DataProvider(name = "irLanguage")
    public Object[][] lang() {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner s = new Scanner(
                "Car         /accord/\n" +
                "Car         /civic/\n" +
                "suv         /landcruzer/\n" +
                "suv         /rangerover/\n" +
                "muv         /innova/\n");
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        while (s.hasNext()) {

            String key = s.next();
            if (!map.containsKey(key))
                map.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());

            map.get(key).add(s.next());

        }
        urlArray = map.get(vehicletype);
        String[][] shades = new String[urlArray.size()][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < urlArray.size(); i++) {
            shades[i][0] = urlArray.get(i).toString();
            shades[i][1] = URL + urlArray.get(i).toString();
            lang = shades[i][0];
            System.out.println(shades[i][0]);

        }

        return shades;
    }
```

Here, the code is working fine. That is , if the input vehicle type is **car** then the output url is www.abc.com/accord/ and www.abc.com/civic/
and if the vehicle type is muv, it only returns www.abc.com/innova/ . This setup works fine for me. But, I wonder if there is any simpler method to do this. 
Can anybody with good knowledge in java can help?

Comment: Removed the Selenium tag since this has nothing to do with Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, I would build a `HashMap` that contains one Key (e.g. "car") and all the desired Values for that Key (e.g. "accord", "civic")

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> vehicles = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> makes = new ArrayList<String>();
makes.add("accord");
makes.add("civic");
vehicles.put("car", makes);
makes.clear();

makes.add("landcruzer");
makes.add("rangerover");
vehicles.put("suv", makes);
makes.clear();

makes.add("innova");
vehicles.put("muv", makes);
makes.clear();
```

Now that you've got the `vehicles` `HashMap` built, you can fetch a Key and get all Values and build your URLs.

```
makes = vehicles.get("car");
for (String make : makes)
{
    System.out.println("www.abc.com/" + make);
}
```